# Matlab: How to obtain a new vector of measurements

Tags: matlab, vector

I have the following vectors,where V1,V2 are measures relative to the heights Y1,Y2:

```
Y1 = [32 115 174 468 818 1067 1268 1399 1446 1484 1503 1588 1608 1665 1761 1879 1918 2037 2138 2148];
V1 = [71 54 54 59 65 70 74 76 77 78 70 18 18 19 23 29 26 20 16 15];
Y2 = [32 49 137 782 791 1171 1255 1461 1471 1538 1683 1781 1860 1890 1910 1960 2102 2268 2467 2563];
V2 = [44 58 54 49 49 48 48 38 38 35 19 13 19 32 44 47 57 72 57 50];
```

[image: interpolation]

I would to obtain a **new** **V2** vector (**V2_new**) that will has the "green circles" **on the blue line** ,but I have not an idea how to do.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the we can assume that `v` is a function of `y` (`v(y)`)then you could use interpolation:

```
% Find where green circles "should" be on blue line by y2
v2_interp = interp1(y1, v1, y2); 

% You can ease the equality criteria if you wish
matches = (v2_interp == v2); 

v2_matches = v2(matches);
y2_matches = y2(matches);
```

[image]

Comment: Yes v is a function of y (v(y)), but if I  plot(V1,Y1,v2_interp, Y1,'ro'); I obtain the new image in your Answer (I'm sorry but it is not possible to upload images in the comments' area)and I have also "nan" that I do not need

Comment: Where do you get the NaNs? In the beginning and/or the end of v2_interp? You should ignore these. With your sample data, Y2 gets to 2563 while Y1 only gets to 2148, interpolation fails there. But you also know for certain that these samples are not on the line.

Comment: At the end of v2_interp

Comment: So As I wrote, you should ignore them. These are not on the line.